# JS split array to make sub-arrays and find a union set of all arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

I've data in the following format:

> Element 1: "Europe > Germany > Berlin > Main Office" (Object)
>
> Element 2: "America > United States > Headquarters" (Object)
>
> Element 3: "America > United States > NY > Main Office" (Object)
>
> Element 4: "America > United States > NY > Sub Office" (Object)
>
> Element 5: "United Kingdom > England > London > Main Office" (Object)

First I'm trying to split the array based on ">" character, and create a tree of all elements in the following format (vanilla js/es6):

```js
"Europe": {
  "Germany": {
    "Berlin": {
      "Main Office": "Object"
    }
  }
},
```

My attempt:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(elements).forEach((el) => {

    let 
    stringIHave = el.name, // "Europe > Germany > Berlin > Main Office" 
    keywordsArr = stringIHave.split( " > " ),
    arrayTree =  new Array();

    Array.prototype.slice.call(keywordsArr).forEach((subEl) => {
        //arrayTree.push(el.toString()); // Result: {"Europe", "Germany", "Berlin", "Main Office" }  

        // What I'm Seeking:  
        // "Europe": { "Germany": { "Berlin": { "Main Office": "Object" } } },

    });

});
```

Once we have the data formatted, we need to find the union (or one single array) of all arrays, like below:

```
[
"Europe": {
  "Germany": {
    "Berlin": {
      "Main Office": "Object"
    }
  }
},

"America": {
  "United States": {
    "Headquarters",
    "NY": {
      "Main Office": "Object",
      "Sub Office": "Object"
    }
  }
},

"United Kingdom": {
  "England": {
    "London": {
      "Main Office": "Object"
    }
  }
}
]
```

I've been trying to using `Array.from(new Set(masterArray))` for finding the union of all arrays, but no dice!

Comment: So your data is an array of strings?

Comment: @Addis Yes, all strings!

Comment: Ok, but `{ "Main Office" }` is not a valid data type niether it is an object. Objects should be key-value pairs.

Comment: @Addis True! Main Office, Sub Office, and Headquarters would later link to their relative objects. I didn't want to complex the question and wanted to tackle one issue at a time.

Comment: @Addis Just updated the question!

Comment: Do you mean `"Main Office": "Object"`?

Comment: @Addis Correct, sorry for the poorly formatted question!

Comment: Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function for each string in the array to construct the nested objects.

```js
const data = [
  'Element 1: Europe > Germany > Berlin > Main Office',

  'Element 2: America > United States > Headquarters',

  'Element 3: America > United States > NY > Main Office',

  'Element 4: America > United States > NY > Sub Office',

  'Element 5: United Kingdom > England > London > Main Office'
]
 
 //remove the string before ':' on all array elements.
 let data1 = data.map(str => str.slice( str.indexOf(':') +1, -1 ));
 
 let arrayTree = data1.map(str => convertToTree(str)) ;
 
 console.log(arrayTree);

 function convertToTree(str) {
     let places = str.split('>');
   
     if(places.length === 1) {
         return ({"Main Office": "Object"});
     }
   
     //the first part of the splited string should be the property and the remaining part will be converted 
     //back to string and sent to the recursive function until the result of the split becomes a single element

     return ({ [places[0]]:convertToTree(places.slice(1).join('>'))  });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't merge all arrays and find the union set!